# How to load image from Contact into ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-contentprovider

I have one ImageView component and wants to load image from contact

I have this URI

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/799/photo
```

What should I do??

Comment: What did you try so far??

Comment: @Dhruv Patel Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
public Uri getContactImage() {
    try {
        Cursor cur = this.ctx.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND "
                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                null);
        if (cur != null) {
            if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                return null; // no photo
            }
        } else {
            return null; // error in cursor process
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
            .parseLong(getId()));
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Use above method as below:

```
Uri u = getContactImage();
if (u != null) {
        mImageView.setImageURI(u);
} else {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
```

Comment: yeah, It works.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) you can find how to get an inputstream for the image.

Then, do [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to get a bitmap.

To put it in the view, do [`myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Comment: So.Can you give me a sample code of "photo from contact", because I referred ao may tutorials but fails